# Disassemble spring-assisted sash window

Tags: windows

I know how to remove the sashes from an old-style counterweighted window. But some of the windows in my house appear to have spring cylinders to assist them instead, and they travel in a plastic track rather than just the frame, stops, and parting bead. If anyone's familiar with these and knows how to dismount/remount these sashes, they really could use reglazing before winter...

View at top of sash showing cylinder housing lift assist spring. Note no obvious release points.
[image: spring cylinder above sash]!

View with inner dash lifted, showing track acting as parting stop.
[image: below sash showing track acting as parting stop and weatherseal]

Best guess I've got is unscrew inner stops, remove screws holding track, remove screws holding springs, and take track/spring/sashes out together (at least on one side). Feels like there should be an easier answer. But I may be spoiled by modern tilt-outs

Comment: Some photos might be helpful.

Comment: Very true; will add...

Comment: What is your plan after you get them out?

Comment: Plan is remove putty, replace, reinstall. Unless I can retrofit better insulating panes while I'm at it...?

Comment: There are insulated replacement panels that will go right in there, Marvin makes the sash and vinyl liners, replacing the aluminum ones you have.     http://www.marvin.com/marvin/windows/double-hung-tilt-pac   I do not work for them, but I would recommend this to any old house owner.

Comment: Hm. Worth a look; tnx. I'm not ready to do full replacement on these, but...

Comment: @jack:  Very interesting. I wasn't aware there was still a lighter-weight alterative to inserts. Wish they gave a bit more info about the details of installation and prices; will have to research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sash were set in place with the guides. To remove them you will need to remove the inside window stops to expose the edge of the track. You will also need to remove the fasteners that are in the track, one of which is visible in your picture at the bottom. There may only be that one fastener, but there should be another at the top, and depending on the whim of the fabricator, there may be more. Two are only ever needed on each side, top and bottom.